# How to add two textfield timings and display in third textfield

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone App Development,Plz help me.
In my tableview i added custom button's at rightside of each cell and named ShowStartDate,ShowEndDate,Worked.
When i click on the ShowStartDate Custom Button i navigate to another view controller there i selected date and time(DatePicker) and i am displaying this date on ShowStartDate CustomButton.
Similarly when i click on SelectDuration Custom Button i navigate to another view controller there i selected time and i am displaying this time on SelectDuration CustomButton.
When this both work completed,i have to display the time automatically at ShowEndDate  custom Button by adding,
The date and time at ShowStartDate is Sat 30 Jun 2012 10:09 AM.
The time at SelectDuration is 11:00 hours
How can i display the time at ShowEndDate automatically like Sat 30 jun 2012 09::09 PM.

Plz help me which type NSTimer Class i have to use.

Comment: Put some code,how can we guess??

Comment: Hi,Thanks for ur reply.Actually i am doing this App(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aOBkIkBqd8) Plz watch this short video,you can understand what my requirement is.In the first cell of tableview i create custom button(ShowStartDate) i enter date and time by using UIDatepicker.In the third custom button(worked) i enter only time using date picker.when we enter these two details  the second  custom button(ShowEndDate) is automatically updated.How is it Possible i need Help for it.Plz watch this short video u can easily understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use - `- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds` method.

```
NSDate *mydate = ;// Which you already have
int hours = ;//You already have this

NSTimeInterval hoursInSeconds = hours * 60 * 60;
NSDate *dateAfterAddingHours = [mydate dateByAddingTimeInterval:hoursInSeconds];

// Now you can display dateAfterAddingHours in your third text field
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for ur reply.Actually i am doing this App(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aOBkIkBqd8) Plz watch this short video,you can understand what my requirement is.In the first cell of tableview i create custom button(ShowStartDate) i enter date and time by using UIDatepicker.In the third custom button(worked) i enter only time using date picker.when we enter these two details  the second  custom button(ShowEndDate) is automatically updated.How is it Possible i need Help for it.Plz watch this short video u can easily understand.

Comment: @user1240249 - i have checked that, and the piece of code that i have posted will do same kind of stuff, have you tried it. Also as mentioned in the app there you need to handle both hours and minutes so you can update the above code accordingly.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for ur reply.I understand your answer,but i am unable to assign values to *mydate,hours.Actually my data is on custom buttons how can assign button value to *mydate,hours. Plz tell me if u have any idea.

Comment: Can you show me what is there exactly in hours and date which you are getting.

Comment: Date- Sat 30 Jun 2012 10:00 AM (on first custom button)                              Time:05:00 (on third custom button) . By adding both I have to show sat 30 Jun 2012 03:00 PM on second custom button.

Comment: Date must be NSDate Object, but what is time, is it a string?

Comment: Hi,I have date and time on custom buttons.For NSDate object i am assigning date as NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a"];
    NSDate *date=[df dateFromString:btn1.titleLabel.text]; But for int hours i have to assign btn3.titlelabel.text,but it is giving error.How can i assign the custom button value to int hours.I am storing btn3 value in string as NSString *strHours=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",btn3.titleLabel.text]; And now how can i assign this string value to int hours.Plz help me.

Comment: string to int conversion is quite simple, use [strHours intValue];

Comment: Hi,exactly this is what is tried after sending message to you.Date is displayed on 3rd custom button but i am not receiving exact time on 3rd custom button.